# PHP - pdo presistent connection and Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I run a cron job in my cpanel(plesk) which starts with a PDO persistent connection to my sql server which I initiated like this

```
`$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME,DBADMIN,DBPASS,[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true]);`
```

Now with this `$pdo` object I do many select and update queries, But in the end I close the presisent connection

```
`$pdo = null;` // last line in the script
```

But what if the script gets a Fatal error in between and halt unexpectedly that way it will never reach to the last line (`$pdo = null`) so what would happen in that case

would the connection will always be open? or it will be closed automatically somehow?

Comment: It will be closed as soon as the php proccess stops.

Comment: @malukenho Thanks :)